# Is there a way to place node name to the right in PlantUML?

Tags: plantuml

To increase readability I would like to place (interface) node names to the right of the node. Is this somehow possible?

```
@startuml

left to right direction
() "longer_interface_name" as interface
[component one] --> interface
[component two] --> interface
[component three] --> interface
[component four] --> interface
[component five] --> interface

@enduml
```

leads to

[image]

but I'd like to have something like

[image]

Comment: It's not solving your problem so I will put this in a comment : From my experience and after another look at the PlantUML guide, I don't think there is a way to change this setting. I guess the only way to make the label more legible would be to remove the `left to right direction` command.

Comment: Yes, but the `left to right` is there for a reason. My actual names are longer and the components are more than 5. without it it would be an endless horizontal scrolling that won't fit on a screen. That's why I thought if I can change the arrangement of the nodes I should be able to change the arrangement of node vs text as well.